# Overall function doesn't run even though console.log gives proper result

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Pig Latin assignment.  Able to get correct return to print via console.log, but script returns undefined if run in the node.js test.

need to debug before moving forward.

tried moving the final function call elsewhere in the script. i think maybe it is because of scoping, but this is only my second JS project so i'm really a newbie.

```
function pigLatin(word) {
  // Global variables
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  const splitWord = word
    .toLowerCase()
    .trim()
    .split("");


  // Slice Word at first Vowel to end
  function firstPart(param1, param2) {
    for (let v = 0; v < vowels.length; v++) {
      for (let w = 0; w < splitWord.length; w++) {
        if (vowels[w] === splitWord[v]) {
          return `${splitWord.slice(v, splitWord.length).join("")}`;
        } else if (splitWord.length === 1) {
          return `${""}`;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Slice word from First Letter to Vowel & if first letter is vowel
  function secondPart(param1, param2) {
    for (let v = 0; v < vowels.length; v++) {
      for (let w = 0; w < splitWord.length; w++) {
        if (vowels[w] === splitWord[0]) {
          return `${splitWord.splice([0], [v]).join("")}yay`;
        } else if (vowels[w] === splitWord[v]) {
          return `${splitWord.splice([0], [v]).join("")}ay`;
        } else if (splitWord.length === 1) {
          return `${splitWord.join("")}yay`;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Combine returns from firstPart and secondPart
  const result1 = firstPart(vowels, splitWord);
  const result2 = secondPart(vowels, splitWord);

  function combine(param1, param2) {
    return `${param1}${param2}`;
  }

  console.log(combine(result1, result2));
}
```

expected results are to have the script run successfully. but when combine(result1, result2) is called outside of console.log, script return undefined.

Comment: what returns undefined? Can you show it with how you call your method?

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/fdb9807s/

Comment: Replace `console.log(combine(result1, result2));` with `return combine(result1, result2);`? The question is somewhat unclear because "script returns undefined" makes no sense – scripts can't return anything; only functions can return values. Not sure what "the node.js test" is, either.

Comment: MultiplyByZer0: that resolved the issue. the node.js test is a test environment the school setup with mocha to ensure that we are getting the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'word' is undefined in

```
const splitWord = word
    .toLowerCase()
    .trim()
    .split("");
```

add by example

```
var word = 'test';
```

on the first rule of the script to get it working for a start

Edit: this is if you forget the word in the first place when calling the function :)